# Spark doesnt let me count my joined dataframes

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

New at Spark Jobs and I have the following problem.

When I run a count on any of the newly joined dataframes, the job runs for ages and spills memory to disk. Is there any logic error in here?

```
    // pass spark configuration
    val conf = new SparkConf()
      .setMaster(threadMaster)
      .setAppName(appName)

    // Create a new spark context
    val sc = new SparkContext(conf)

    // Specify a SQL context and pass in the spark context we created
    val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc)


    // Create three dataframes for sent and clicked files. Mark them as raw, since they will be renamed
    val dfSentRaw = sqlContext.read.parquet(inputPathSent)
    val dfClickedRaw = sqlContext.read.parquet(inputPathClicked)
    val dfFailedRaw  = sqlContext.read.parquet(inputPathFailed)



    // Rename the columns to avoid ambiguity when accessing the fields later
    val dfSent = dfSentRaw.withColumnRenamed("customer_id", "sent__customer_id")
      .withColumnRenamed("campaign_id", "sent__campaign_id")
      .withColumnRenamed("ced_email", "sent__ced_email")
      .withColumnRenamed("event_captured_dt", "sent__event_captured_dt")
      .withColumnRenamed("riid", "sent__riid")


    val dfClicked = dfClickedRaw.withColumnRenamed("customer_id", "clicked__customer_id")
      .withColumnRenamed("event_captured_dt", "clicked__event_captured_dt")
    val dfFailed = dfFailedRaw.withColumnRenamed("customer_id", "failed__customer_id")


    // LEFT Join with CLICKED on two fields, customer_id and campaign_id
    val dfSentClicked = dfSent.join(dfClicked, dfSent("sent__customer_id") === dfClicked("clicked__customer_id")
      && dfSent("sent__campaign_id") === dfClicked("campaign_id"), "left")
     dfSentClicked.count() //THIS WILL NOT WORK

val dfJoined = dfSentClicked.join(dfFailed, dfSentClicked("sent__customer_id") === dfFailed("failed__customer_id")
      && dfSentClicked("sent__campaign_id") === dfFailed("campaign_id"), "left")
```

Why cant these two/three dataframes be counted anymore? Did I mess up some indexing by renaming?

Thank you!

[image]

Comment: A few questions: What is the error you are seeing? Have you tried doing a count on the pre-join dataframes? Have you tried the consolidating your column names across the different dataframes and calling this join (`join(right: DataFrame, usingColumns: Seq[String], joinType: String)`)?

Comment: 1. Its no real error, i just feel the job runs on forever and spills ("UnsafeExternalSorter spilling memory to disk")
2. Yes, Counting works - prejoin
3. I dont get that point, what did I do differently?

Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: What's the size of the data? And what are you cluster memory configurations?

Comment: I run in locally in intelliJ with xmx2048m on a 32gb machine (should have mentioned that). The data is a subset of whats on the cluster. About 1 GB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That `count` call is the only actual materialization of your Spark job here, so it's not really `count` that is a problem but the shuffle that is being done for the `join` right before it. You don't have enough memory to do the join without spilling to disk. Spilling to disk in a shuffle is a very easy way to make your Spark jobs take forever =).

One thing that really helps prevent spilling with shuffles is having more partitions. Then there is less data moving through the shuffles at any given time. You can set `spark.sql.shuffle.partitions` which controls the number of partitions used by Spark Sql in a join or aggregation. It defaults to 200, so you can trying a higher setting. http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#other-configuration-options

You could increase the heap size of your local Spark allocation and/or increase the fraction of memory usable for shuffles by increasing `spark.shuffle.memoryFraction` (defaults to 0.4) and decreasing `spark.storage.memoryFraction` (defaults to 0.6). The Storage fraction is used for example when you make a `.cache` call and you might not care about that.

If you are so inclined to absolutely avoid the spills outright, you can turn off spilling by setting `spark.shuffle.spill` to `false`. I believe this will throw an exception if you run out of memory and need to spill instead of silently taking forever and could help you configure your memory allocation faster.